# IndentationError In Python while Adding Progress Bar

Tags: python

I was trying to put a progress bar in my programm, but an error comes up. I don't know how to use it correctly so the progress bar will be printed out.

```
import time
import sys

toolbar_width = 40

# setup toolbar
sys.stdout.write("[%s]" % (" " * toolbar_width))
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdout.write("\b" * (toolbar_width+1)) # return to start of line, after '['

for i in xrange(toolbar_width):
    time.sleep(0.1) # do real work here
    # update the bar
    sys.stdout.write("-")
    sys.stdout.flush()

sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

This is the error that I get:

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: IndentationError means you messed up indentation in your code. We can't really help you here, because it looks ok, you must have hit spacebar by accident or something... since the only unindent is in the last line, the bug sits probably there

Comment: You are mixing tabs and spaces. Don't do that. Use your editor to replace all tabs with spaces for indentation.

Comment: @Dunno, okay. but how to use this code?

Comment: @MartijnPieters how did you catch that? :O

Comment: @Dunno: experience. That's the most common way to get this error message while the spacing *looks* correct.

Comment: @MartijnPieters wow, now that you mention it, there are dozens of duplicates on SO concerning this error.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an indentation error. Run `python -tt` on your script to verify you didn't mix tabs and spaces.

Best practice is to only uses spaces or tabs, not mix the two. Most projects and certainly the [Python Style Guide PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommend you use spaces only.

Comment: Done with that, another error comes up. `print " [+] Loading, Please Wait... [%s]" % (" " * toolbar_width))
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @ScriptKiddies: That doesn't match up with what you posted; you have one `)` too many on that line. `print` is not a function, but you forgot to remove the closing `)` from the `sys.stdout.write()` function call.

Comment: If i remove `)` , i will get another error. `sys.stdout.flush()
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @ScriptKiddies: Note: Stack Overflow is not a interactive debugging service. I cannot help you out in comments indefinitely. You seem to have removed *both* closing parens now; the line should be `print " [+] Loading, Please Wait... [%s]" % (" " * toolbar_width)` (unless you are using Python 3, where it would be `print(" [+] Loading, Please Wait... [%s]" % (" " * toolbar_width))`